# JavaScript changes src and [] automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

so, i have a website im building just for something to do.

I do not have a lot of experience with javascript but i want this link of code to apply to 4 buttons and it changes the src and whatever is between the square brackets based on what button it is.

```
function changehome(){
    document.images["homeimg"].src= "homelinku.jpg";
    return true;
}
```

Can anyone show me how this can be done, i expected it to be possible using the parentheses?

Comment: You should add more code, like HTML, to help us get a sense of the context in which you're using it.

Comment: Show us you HTML please so we can provide a better way of doing this.

Comment: all code can be viewed at

isaacscarrow.zapto.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define function with parameters and pass their to the function:

```
<input type="button" onClick = "changehome('homeimg', 'homelinku.jpg')" />
```

...

```
function changehome(img, src){
    document.images[img].src= src;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hey, im having a little trouble again. this is what i have, could get what you said to work. but i am still trying. 

isaacscarrow.zapto.org

maybe you can help me out a bit.

Comment: Looks like it's not code problem. From browser console: Image corrupt or truncated: http://119.224.88.82:7625/contactu.jpg

Comment: if u look at the source code for it, it does work how i have it, i was just hoping to change it so that i type out less. because i am creating a new function for each image, and it would be better if i could use the same function for all of them.